# Determine reason for X.509 certifcate revocation?

Tags: ssl, certificate

I'm trying to connect to Human Rights Watch. The page is not loading and the browser is not giving me much information. The browser states *"Peer's Certificate has been revoked. (Error code: sec_error_revoked_certificate)"*.

I'd like to learn more and possibly ignore the issue, but the browser does not allow me to view the certificate or provide the reason the certificate was revoked:

[image]

From OpenSSL command line tool, I believe Symantec issued the certificate (see below). Adding `-crl_check` and `-crl_check_all` does not provide more information.

How can I determine the reason and obtain more information about the certificate revocation?

---

```
$ openssl s_client -connect hrw.org:443 -servername hrw.org -tls1 | openssl x509 -text -noout
depth=2 C = US, O = "VeriSign, Inc.", OU = VeriSign Trust Network, OU = "(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", CN = VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            76:59:2a:47:97:66:58:7a:44:a8:8b:b4:0e:d1:be:02
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, O=Symantec Corporation, OU=Symantec Trust Network, CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar  5 00:00:00 2015 GMT
            Not After : Mar  5 23:59:59 2019 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=New York, L=New York, O=Human Rights Watch, OU=Online, CN=hrw.org
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:e6:ec:72:2e:03:b2:54:5a:dd:2a:78:08:67:bc:
                    5a:e0:6c:c3:6e:20:70:f1:86:c6:de:78:93:15:b4:
                    02:c3:8f:77:98:99:d1:8f:25:4c:27:72:6a:0c:3e:
                    aa:a2:8a:53:10:07:af:4d:9d:be:9c:e6:79:0c:62:
                    50:5a:b2:27:dc:f1:13:a2:9f:16:5f:c3:3e:ad:44:
                    f4:7e:be:81:4a:24:7d:ac:1c:e9:b7:db:47:39:41:
                    41:d5:db:9c:5b:8d:35:07:30:fe:15:70:8e:0d:92:
                    c0:9e:f8:81:b3:00:72:10:42:b0:50:81:98:a4:d7:
                    dd:bb:fe:7d:b4:78:19:bc:ae:77:45:ff:a5:b9:ad:
                    2e:84:46:be:2e:a0:68:f9:b2:22:2e:f1:66:00:d6:
                    13:15:2d:50:7e:59:70:bf:53:67:ff:2c:30:38:fc:
                    c9:01:8d:6d:1a:62:fc:1f:df:02:16:27:3c:e6:c7:
                    7d:d8:68:14:79:99:e7:9c:b6:4d:2d:01:b4:77:3c:
                    44:8e:f9:67:5d:8e:7d:b3:9f:4b:02:ab:4c:53:c2:
                    92:b7:d0:8b:2a:12:68:1e:47:e9:8d:87:f8:a4:4f:
                    b1:d2:ee:0e:2d:3c:cc:19:fd:f5:f1:46:40:c7:54:
                    c4:5e:9b:58:6f:96:53:49:81:4f:0f:a6:0e:64:88:
                    30:59
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:features.hrw.org, DNS:hrw.org
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://ss.symcb.com/ss.crl

            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: 2.16.840.1.113733.1.7.54
                  CPS: https://d.symcb.com/cps
                  User Notice:
                    Explicit Text: https://d.symcb.com/rpa

            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:5F:60:CF:61:90:55:DF:84:43:14:8A:60:2A:B2:F5:7A:F4:43:18:EF

            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://ss.symcd.com
                CA Issuers - URI:http://ss.symcb.com/ss.crt

    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         92:72:97:e5:92:1a:d8:f4:8e:fe:39:4a:8a:f1:ec:73:4f:5f:
         66:f9:27:fe:bf:9e:e9:c7:fa:49:fb:3c:4b:64:5b:2c:d8:e4:
         9c:a2:85:49:03:40:fd:de:a2:37:f1:b9:87:bc:72:23:6d:72:
         b7:a4:79:99:d0:79:e8:1d:20:6a:cc:bf:88:59:55:26:77:22:
         8c:c9:54:81:44:c9:d4:13:2c:3f:e4:2c:f5:9a:5e:51:e2:fe:
         a4:a0:28:d1:cd:71:b8:04:72:6a:26:b2:41:f8:c5:13:9f:82:
         72:93:ae:fc:11:0a:fd:38:2c:ef:64:64:e8:51:68:a8:1d:d4:
         3e:9e:56:60:55:26:6c:ff:a5:27:46:01:89:57:ab:50:7b:27:
         cc:20:04:9f:c9:2c:6e:ff:7a:fd:23:e6:d4:bb:ab:3a:d6:19:
         12:5b:0e:35:b3:f0:59:fd:3e:53:62:f7:6e:bf:a3:af:51:74:
         fb:95:a1:0e:04:a6:ff:42:0a:57:4d:50:62:30:05:26:57:0b:
         ae:4e:44:78:45:8b:1a:4b:dc:a8:32:02:19:0f:04:e9:1f:85:
         89:a2:16:fb:3f:2f:82:85:c4:c6:18:8c:19:0e:4f:13:d2:98:
         ff:2b:c2:08:c8:a0:3b:76:0d:19:48:f6:a3:f7:fc:78:5c:4e:
         63:48:83:29
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no useful reason information in the revocation lists (CRL) or protocol (OCSP). There is no textual representation for detailed information but all you have is a single bit.

Looking at the OCSP verification process in detail I'll see the following details for the response:

```
 revocationTime: 2015-03-06 15:25:37 (UTC)
 revocationReason: unspecified (0)
```

Given that the certificate is only valid from 2015-03-05 this means that the certificate was revoked already 1 day after it was issued, for unspecified reason.

Please note also that hrw.org is a different IP address than www.hrw.org. www.hrw.org is behind a content delivery network and shares the same certificate with sites like api.weibo.com and various Japanese and Korean domains.

Also note that if you would have used the Chrome browser instead of Firefox you would have not run into this error because Chrome uses it's own mechanism for revocation checks ([CRLsets](https://www.grc.com/revocation/crlsets.htm)) which only include revocations considered important :(

BTW, I think this kind of question is more suitable for security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks. How did you obtain the information? That's kind of what I am interested in. This is a grey area for me because I either (1) know the organization and know how to proceed; or (2) don't know the organization and I don't care. I'm in a condition where neither (1) nor (2) apply.

Comment: @jww: I did a packet capture to get the OCSP response and looked at the details with wireshark. And I've triggered the OCSP response with the Perl module [IO::Socket::SSL](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::SSL) to better control when OCSP lookups are done. Definitely not the way to go for most users :)

Comment: Thanks. I thought I was missing something obvious when it came to fetching the information. BTW, your findings were quite interesting. I found ***`hrw.org`*** via a Google search, so it looks like Google got gamed too. If that's a real Symantec certificate, then Symantec got gamed, too.

Comment: I don’t see anyone getting “gamed“ here. Google also only lists the “www” domain. If the second level domain were compromised, you couldn’t trust the “www” subdomain either. It may simply be a leftover of an earlier/experimental setup. You could contact HRW about the issue.

Comment: @DanielB: I would consider this also an artifact of early experiments and a failure to properly setting up and testing TLS. Otherwise they would not have left a certificate there which got revoked about a year ago.

Comment: @DanielB - I followed a link from a Google ad. I did it to support Google and to show the organization that the ad worked. I can tell you for certain it took me to ***`hrw.org`*** (*q.v.*). I have no idea about experiments and second level domains. I tried to contact Google about the bad search results, but the emails to secure@google.com and security@google.com both bounced. So much for [Well Known Addresses from RFC 2142](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2142.txt)...